# QGIS view point data

Tags: qgis, visualisation

In kepler.gl I can hover over a point and get the corresponding data from the CSV file it was loaded from. Like this.

[image]

Is something like this possible in QGIS?

Comment: yes, you need to turn `show map tips` on

Comment: @Ian it's working. thanks)